# Debbuger of Vue.js TypeScript project with WebStorm doesn't stop at break point

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webstorm

I created new project with WebStorm with TypeScript setting. Then, debugger break point doesn't work.

## My settings

## Version

- node 12.10
- vue/cli 3.11.0

## Project setting

1. Babel
2. TypeScript
3. Router
4. CSS Pre-processors
5. Unit Testing

## Build setting

1. Class Style Syntax => Yes
2. User Babel alongside Typescript => Yes
3. Use historymode => No
4. Css Pre proccessor: Sass/Scss dart-sass

## Code

Debug point is on the `console.log("started")`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

console.log("satarted")

@Component({
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
},
})
export default class App extends Vue {}
</script>

<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Debug setting of WebStorm:

[image]

Then I click debug button, but it not stop at break point.

`package.json, tsconfig.json` and other files are default setting.

Comment: what configuration did you debug - *npm* or *javascript debug*? the former should only be used for starting your app, you need to choose the latter and press *Debug* to get the debugger attached to your browser page

Comment: I am using npm debug.
I'll try attach to brwoser page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should start your application by running (not debugging) **npm serve** run configuration and then choose the **JavaScript debug** configuration and press **Debug**.

See https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2018/01/working-with-vue-js-in-webstorm/, *Debugging the app* section

Answer (score 3):

If your program doesn't stop at the breakpoint, it usually means your program doesn't execute the code where your breakpoint is in. Or you are looking at the wrong place. In frontend applications, your console can be viewed within your browser by pressing f12. I would also recommend using the Vue Devtools extension, it's pretty useful.